# how to delete related data that is loaded by include()-method in entity framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I searched for hours to find a solution but I couldn't find it. 
The problem is that I'm loading data using the entity framework and the include() method. That looks like

```
Dim Test = (From o in DataContext.Orders.Include("OrderDetails")
            select o).FirstOrDefault
```

Loading, editing and saving of the data works fine. When I add data to the related OrderDetails property of "Test" and remove it by the Remove()-Method of this EntityCollection, the data is removed from the list, but it is added to the database.

Does anyone know how I can delete such related data properly?

Thanks

Comment: Did you call SaveChanges after removing entities?

Comment: I don't call SaveChanges at this moment because then all other changes are also saved to the database. I just want to temporaly add related data, modify it or remove it and then save all changes at the end. Or is this the wrong way? Do I have to call SaveChanges after every change of the data?